# Switchyard validation takes a long time Jboss Developer Studio

Tags: eclipse, switchyard, jboss-developer-studio

I am working in the Jboss Developer Studio IDE. Here is my version information:

```
JBoss Developer Studio

Version: 7.1.1.GA
Build id: GA-v20140314-2145-B688
Build date: 20140314-2145
```

When importing a switchyard project, my studio will validate the switchyard xml for approximately 30 seconds, on every second save. Here is the photo of what I am referencing:

[image]

Has anyone experienced this before? How can I instruct JBoss Developer Studio to be more intelligent about caching?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After weeks of troubleshooting, I figured out that the problem was related to my network. Ensure that you do NOT have proxy settings enabled, as this trips up Jboss Developer Studio. My compilation/validation time is now instantanious